# Servicestack user session not working

Tags: c#, session, authentication, servicestack, mod-mono

I have an API written in ServiceStack and I am attempting to build in authentication for clients. At the moment this API will only be accessed by Android clients (Xamarin / C#). The API itself is running on a Debian server with Apache / mod_mono

After reading up on Github, I am still not 100% sure how to put this together in such a way that... once the client has provided valid credentials (For testing, basic HTTP authentication) the user gets a session and the credentials are not checked again on subsequent requests from the same session.

**AppHost Class:**

```
{
public class AppHost
    : AppHostBase
{       
    public AppHost() //Tell ServiceStack the name and where to find your web services
        : base("Service Call Service", typeof(ServiceCallsService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

        // Session storage
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

        // auth feature and session feature
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new[] { new userAuth() }
        ) { HtmlRedirect = null } );
    }

    public class userAuth : BasicAuthProvider
    {
        public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
        {
            peruseAuth peruseAuthHandler= new peruseAuth();
            errorLogging MyErrorHandler = new errorLogging() ; 
            if (peruseAuthHandler.ValidateUser(authService, userName, password))
            {
                try
                {
                    var session = (AuthUserSession)authService.GetSession(false);
                    session.UserAuthId = userName;
                    session.IsAuthenticated = true;
                    return true;
                }
                catch(Exception ex) 
                {
                   MyErrorHandler.LogError(ex, this) ;
                    return false ; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("False");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**The JsonServiceClient:** *(Just the "login" event)*

```
        btnLogin.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Set credentials from EditText elements in Main.axml
                client.SetCredentials(txtUser.Text, txtPass.Text);

                // Force the JsonServiceClient to always use the auth header
                client.AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true;

            };
```

I've been doing a bit of logging, and it seems that every time the client performs an action their username/password is being checked against the database. Is there something wrong here, or is this the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Basic Auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) where the credentials are sent on each request it's expected.

In order for the ServiceClient to retain the Session cookies that have been authenticated you should set the `RememberMe` flag when you authenticate, e.g using [CredentialsAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AuthTests.cs#L395):

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);
var authResponse = client.Send(new Authenticate {
    provider = "credentials", 
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "p@55word",
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

[Behind the scenes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions) this attaches the user session to the `ss-pid` cookie (permanent session cookie), which the client retains and resends on subsequent requests from that ServiceClient instance.